# Image, having source URL pointing to site's attachment image, is not displayed. Wrong way?

Tags: google-apps-script

There is a task to display an image, which is placed to a Google App Site, from a Google App Site script, i.e. code looks like `UiApp.getActiveApplication().createImage('http://....');`. The image is uploaded to the Site by clicking the `Insert->Image` Page Editor menu item, it is stored to the Site's Attachments and is visible if to drop an Image Gadget with a uploaded image to a page. The Image Gadget URL has the following format `https://sites.google.com/a/.../image00.png`. I pointed this URL as the `createImage` `URL` parameter but the running script does not display the image and its URL is `https://static-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url=https://sites.google.com/a/.../image00.png&container=focus&gadget=...&rewriteMime=image/*&no_expand=1&refresh=60`. Opening this link a new web browser window outputs

> This webpage is not found.... Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.

Is this way wrong? If yes, how is correctly to implement this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your site public ? If not, [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=912) may be of relevance

Comment: My site is private and a solution to make it public is not suitable in my case. It would be nice if it is possible to make public only an image but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: Why not create an auxiliary site just for this purpose ? this one could be public, images in its container would remain invisible from this site if you don't put them on pages.